# Reloading a UITableView cell height and contents

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to reload the size and contents of a UITableView, but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code and the logs, I can't figure out why it isn't working…

**Code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
NSIndexPath *myIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];        
    [self tableView:feed heightForRowAtIndexPath:myIndex];
    [self tableView:feed cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndex];
}
```

**Logs**

*I'm logging the index path in heightForRowAtIndexPath, I think there might be an issue there*

> 2014-08-06 20:26:36.285 App[42159:a0b]  2 indexes [0, 0]
>
> 2014-08-06 20:26:36.287 App[42159:a0b]  2 indexes [0, 1]
>
> 2014-08-06 20:26:37.836 App[42159:a0b]  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
>
> 2014-08-06 20:26:37.864 App[42159:a0b]  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

Comment: So, what did you change exactly? Also, did you try `[feed reloadData]`?

Comment: When you call heightForRowAtIndexPath you aren't DOING anything, that method RETURNS the current height for the row.

Answer (score 2):

You should never call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` or `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` directly. Instead, you should either use `[tableView reloadData]` or something like this:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. it's working alright for a few seconds then it seems to reload the cells again which doesn't work too well with my code. Not too sure why this is happening

Comment: Sounds like you're calling the function responsible for triggering the reloading multiple times somehow.

Answer (score 0):

for reload a UITableViewCell you must use the method ReloadRowAtIndexPath, your code below

```
[self.feed beginUpdates]
for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) 
{
    NSIndexPath *myIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];        
    [self.feed reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[myIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
[self.feed endUpdates]
```